# Is possible to adapt this java code to android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to adapt this java code from this webpage http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/27950-steganography/ to be used on the android sdk.

It has ImageIO, WritableRaster and things from java.awt. If its possible please tell me how!

Thanks

Comment: You can have regular java-class not heiriting from activity. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want to hide text in a image but, I can't use this code because of awt things.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to adapt this java code from this webpage http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/27950-steganography/ to be used on the android sdk.

Is steganography possible using the Android SDK? Yes. You would manipulate the `byte[]` of a `Bitmap`, either in Java code, in native code via the NDK, or perhaps using Renderscript Compute.

Can you perhaps leverage the steganographic algorithms from that code when you write your Android implementation? Presumably yes.

However, as you note, that code depends heavily upon classes that are not part of Android, which is why would you be better served starting with the algorithm and creating a native Android implementation from there, rather than trying to "adapt" the AWT-dependent Java code directly.

Or, see if somebody already has [an Android steganography library](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20steganography%20library) that you can use.

Comment: BUt what thing I have to do? Use bitmap instead of BufferedImage